# how to list direct subfolders of a folder?

Tags: string, algorithm, filesystems

I am trying to write strings algorithm of listing all subpaths of given path

### Input: a list of paths

```
/a/
/a/b/c/
/a/b/c/d/
/a/x/y/
```

How can i print all direct subfolders of given location?

### Desired inputs-outputs:

- Location: `/`
  Output:

```
/a/
```

- Location: `/a/`
  Output:

```
/a/b/
/a/x/
```

- Location: `/a/b/`
  Output:

```
/a/b/c/
```

I think this is already implemented efficiently in file explorers, ls command, so on.. so not to invent bicycle - does this algorithm has a name? where can i find it?

PS. is it possible to work without having some paths in initial list, like omitting

```
/a/b/
/a/x/
```

or running deduplication is heavier than precreating all in advance and seeking for exact match?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to represent this is to use a tree (filesystems are commonly represented as trees): a data-structure where each node can have a value (say, 'a'), and may have children, which when present, are other nodes (say, 'b' and 'x', for the case of 'a').

After you have read in the tree, it is very easy to answer questions of the form "what children does this node have". Trees are also efficient in the sense that they do not have to store duplicate prefixes.

You can also avoid using a tree, and simply store all paths as a sorted list, array, or vector. This is somewhat less efficient. To find all paths that start with a given path, first find the given path, and then, for each element that starts with that path (which must be contiguous, because the list is sorted), add it to the list of children to be returned.

Comment: I tried to do the thing on a read side, so your offer is to do the job "on write" basically mkdir -p /a/b/c/ should be a heavy operation, splitting path to parts, analyzing if things exists, creating expensive "tree" elements in ram.. basically whole goal was to drop expensive tree structure.. xD, but anyway, thanks for your input!